# Regex Find and group text blocks

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract coherent text blocks (from a markdown) as i need to replace them.

Example:

```
some other text.....
some other text.....

> **_NOTE:_** \
> multi line note text ....\
> note text ....\
> note text ....

## section

Lorem ipsum....

> **_NOTE:_** \
> note text

Lorem ipsum....

> **_NOTE:_** single line note text
```

I am looking for a regular expression that detects blocks starting with `> **_NOTE:_*`, followed by all lines starting with `>` and resulting in 3 groups for this example:

Group 1:

```
> **_NOTE:_** \
> multi line note text ....\
> note text ....\
> note text ....
```

Group 2:

```
> **_NOTE:_** \
> note text
```

Group 3:

```
> **_NOTE:_** single line note text
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regular expression to match the text blocks starting with `>**_NOTE:_`, followed by lines starting with `>` and capture them into groups:

```
(> \*\*_NOTE:_\*\*.*(?:\n>.*|\Z)+)
```

- `(> \*\*_NOTE:_\*\*.*` matches the beginning of a block starting with > `**NOTE:`, followed by any characters.
- `(?:\n>.*|\Z)+)` matches one or more lines starting with `>`, until either a blank line or the end of the input is reached

Comment: You can omit the outer capture group, and in the repeating group you can omit the alternation with `\Z` by making the quantifier `*` like `^> \*\*_NOTE:_\*\*.*(?:\n>.*)*` See https://regex101.com/r/8jQyJy/1